# Error al crear gráfico. AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'bar'

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

total = ( mirar imagen)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ERROR AL CREAR EL GRÁFICO:AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'bar'

`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

````
fig = total.bar(total, x='paises', y= 'visitas',
labels={'titulo':'titulo'}, height=400, hover_data=['titulo'])
fig.show()```
````

Answer (score 1):

La la clase `pandas.DataFrame` no tiene un método `bar`.

Pandas engloba la funcionalidad de los gráficos (actuando como envoltorio para el backend que determines mediante `pandas.options.plotting.backend`, por defecto  [matplotlib](/questions/tagged/matplotlib)) mediante `pandas.DataFrame.plot` / `pandas.Series.plot`.

Tienes dos opciones:

```
total.plot.bar(...)
```

o

```
total.plot(..., kind="bar")
```

Tres observaciones:

- Ten en cuenta que no debes pasar como primer arguemnto el DataFrame.
- Los argumentos `labels`, `height` y `hover_data` son inválidos para Matplotlib, pero no se si usas otro backend. `height` debe ser `width` en todo caso dado que es un gráfico vertical.
- `plot`/`plot.bar` retornan una instancia de `AxesSubplot` no de `Figure` si usas Matplotlib como backend, por lo que no puedes usar `show` sobre él. Si éste es el caso, debes hacer:

  ```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import pandas as pd


    # ....
    total.plot.bar(...)

    plt.show()
  ```